# setInterval closure issue when using functions

Tags: javascript, closures, setinterval

Why does case1 only run once?  Why doesn't var `cnt` (global) get incremented in case2?

```js
var cnt = 0;

var case1 =document.getElementById('case1');

var a = setInterval(myFunction(cnt),1000);
   
function myFunction(cnt){
   console.log('case1',cnt);
   cnt++;
   case1.innerHTML = cnt;
   }
   
var case2 =document.getElementById('case2');

var b = setInterval(function(){myFunction2(cnt)},1000);
function myFunction2(cnt){
   console.log('case2',cnt);
   cnt++;
   case2.innerHTML = cnt;
   }
   
/*   
var case3 =document.getElementById('case3');

var c = setInterval(function(){myFunction3()},1000);
function myFunction3(){
   console.log('case3',cnt);
   cnt++;
   case3.innerHTML = cnt;
   }
   */
```

```html
<div id='case1'></div>

<div id='case2'></div>

<div id='case3'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does case1 only run once?**

The `setInterval` function expects a function object as the first argument.
The argument you have provided (`myFunction(cnt)`) is an execution of the `myFunction` and it returns `undefined`. When the function executed just one time, It shows the `case1` in the console. The `setInterval` function really has no input function here to execute repeatedly.

**Why doesn't var cnt (global) get incremented in case2**

The `cnt` variable you are incrementing in the myFunction2 is really the argument supplied to it. So, it overshadows the global variable.

---

See the corrections I have made.

In case1, I have removed the function execution and it runs repeatedly.

In case2, I have renamed the argument - so, the shadowing is removed.

```js
var cnt = 0;

var case1 =document.getElementById('case1');

var a = setInterval(myFunction,1000);
   
function myFunction(){
   console.log('case1');
   cnt++;
   case1.innerHTML = cnt;
   }
   
var case2 =document.getElementById('case2');

var b = setInterval(function(){myFunction2(cnt)},1000);
function myFunction2(cnt1){
   console.log('case2',cnt1);
   cnt1++;
   case2.innerHTML = cnt1;
   }
   
/*   
var case3 =document.getElementById('case3');

var c = setInterval(function(){myFunction3()},1000);
function myFunction3(){
   console.log('case3',cnt);
   cnt++;
   case3.innerHTML = cnt;
   }
   */
```

```html
<div id='case1'></div>

<div id='case2'></div>

<div id='case3'></div>
```

Comment: thanks, made some minor changes to your solution but all good.